# Using method replaceall of String in Java

Tags: java, android

I want to get from a string only the character: `+,-,/,x` 
But this says `-` is a redundant character range.

```
String operacoes=texto.replaceAll("[^+?-?/?x]+"," ");
```

How can i make this work?

Comment: what is the value of texto ? texto = ?

Comment: it could be for example: 3 + 5 - 2 / 4 x 5. And after that operacoes will be: + - / x with spaces between.

Comment: Do you want output this "+- / x" ?

Comment: I'll give another example because i think you're mistaking.  If texto=3 + 4 - 5 + 4.   Then operacoes will be + - +

Comment: The problem is in the "-"

Comment: I have answered try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `\\` before `-` character. Because `-` character used in regex in various ways like 
`[A-Z] [0- 9]` etc. So to identify `-` you need to put `\\` in java because single `\` doesn't support in string in java.

```
    String texto="3 + 4 - 5 + 4";
    String operacoes=texto.replaceAll("[^+?\\-?/?x]+"," ");
    System.out.println(""+operacoes);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the minus sign using double backslash.

```
String operacoes=texto.replaceAll("[^+?\\-?/?x]+"," ");
```

Since the character `-` is used in regex

Answer (score 0):

```
String texto = "1+2-3/4x5";
String operacoes=texto.replaceAll("[^+?\\-?/?x]+"," ");
System.out.println(operacoes);
```

Produces the output

```
+ - / x
```